# How to resign an APK in Dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart, apk

I am working on an app that installs mods on Ren'Py Android apps (you usually have to do it manually, which is very tedious!), I've got everything ready to go, however, I am stuck in one place... Signing the APK file... To give you an idea of what I want to accomplish, this [ZipSigner](https://zipsigner.fileplanet.com/apk) app does it, and I want to be able to do precisely what is being done here... Any idea how to accomplish this in Dart/Flutter?

I did notice that ZipSigner is [open source](https://github.com/kellinwood/zip-signer), but it is written in Java, and my Java is about as bad as it gets :')

Comment: If you have build-tools from Android SDK installed you can just use `apksigner` for signing the apk. Search for `apksigner.jar` respectively the start scripts `apksigner.bat`/`apksigner.sh`. The JAR file can be directly executed `java -jar apksigner.jar`. Or for app integration the same as library is [apksig.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/apksig?repo=google).

Comment: @Robert guess it should be done programmatically if I understood correctly

Comment: @Netsu your "answer" is in the app description: _ZipSigner is an Android app that is capable of signing Zip, Apk, and
Jar files on the device.  Its purpose is to demonstrate the use of
[**zipsigner-lib**](https://github.com/kellinwood/zip-signer/tree/master/zipsigner-lib), a separate API that does the real work of signing the
files._

Comment: Also, since you're using Flutter you first need to create a plugin by yourself (if a existing package isn't available yet which probably is true because this isn't a common use-case). The Flutter plugin itself will need to implement some way to sign the apk using native android apis (you can implement based on the zipsigner-lib or search for _Signin apk programmatically_ and you will find some apis that you can use to implement your plugin. (Did find something can help you either: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/284e45a/tools/signapk/src/com/android/signapk/SignApk.java).

Comment: From what I have seem Zipsigner and it's library are outdated as they just create JAR signatures (AKA Android signature v1). Modern Android devices require an APK Signature v2 or v3, and toy my knowledge the only way is to get an v2/v3 signature is to use Google apksig library. Andorid is a platform that heavily bases on Java/Kotlin code so learning it is inevitable earlier or later. Working completely in a platform independent language is only possible for very basic apps.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you only need `Jarsigner` or `Apksigner` executables (which are available in the Android SDK tools) to resign an APK.

The full process that I like to follow is :

1. Resigning the APK with `Jarsigner`
2. Verifying the signature with `Jarsigner`
3. Aligning the archive with `Zipalign`
4. Analyzing is everything went well with `Keytool`

I wrote a bash script a while ago to ease this process :
https://github.com/FDuhen/android-resign--script

I didn't try it myself but, in theory, you should be able to embed this script and the associated binaries in a Flutter app, and execute it with a library like https://pub.dev/packages/process_run